# Getting specific value with a checkbox input using on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am replacing standard input checkboxes with images and am running into two main issues with the code below:

1. No matter which image I click on (checkbox input), the value stays the same, instead of changing. (See the console for the printed value).
2. When an input is active, I am wanting to background color to change, but for some reason, on page load, all inputs have the red background color (there shouldn't be any background color). Then if I click on the input, nothing changes.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdg6ka4d/1/)

```js
var interest = $('.interest');
interest.click(function() {
  $('.interestCheck').prop('checked', true);
  var check = $('.interestCheck').val();
  console.log(check);
});
if ($('.interestCheck').prop('checked', true)) {
  $('.interestBox').addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.interest {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.interestBox.active {
  background: red;
}

.interestBox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.interestTitle {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.interestCheck {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Linear Motion</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Linear Motion" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Material Handling</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Material Handling" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Enclosures</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Enclosures" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```

Comment: I added a concise and straight forward answer including some explanation. If you still have questions, feel free to ask me in the comments. Let me know if my answer worked for you

Comment: @MihaiT You do know that the OP get noticed of every new answer right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to add a context to your jQuery selectors.

You can do that by adding `this` as the second parameter of your jQuery selectors : `$('yourSelector',this)`.

- If you want to check/uncheck the checkboxes at every click, you need to replace

`$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked',true)`

By

`$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'));`

- Plus, your last `if` can be replaced by a simple `.toggleClass` and needs to be inside your `click` handler.

```js
var interest = $('.interest');
interest.click(function() {
  $('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked', !$('.interestCheck', this).prop('checked'));
  var check = $('.interestCheck', this).val();
  console.log(check);
  $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.interest {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.interestBox.active {
  background: red;
}

.interestBox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.interestTitle {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.interestCheck {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Linear Motion</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Linear Motion" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Material Handling</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Material Handling" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Enclosures</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Enclosures" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: I would improve this by not calling `$('.interestCheck', this)` all the time. Which is equivalent to doing `$( this ).find('.interestCheck')`. Every time you do `$( this )`, jQuery is re-searching the DOM for that element. Since you already have a jQuery object that references what this is in the event handler, just re-use that reference. Replace `$('.interestCheck', this)` with `var $check = $( this ).find( '.interestCheck' )`. Then re-use the variable. The [code might look like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34e6680c78e0669d421644abdbbd5f3f).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this:

If you don't use `$(this)` inside your click function, then the code doesn't know what element you clicked, because `$('.interestCheck').val()` will return the first objects value.

You can also just `$('.interestCheck',this)`

```
var interest = $('.interest');
interest.click(function() {
  $(this).find('.interestCheck').prop('checked', !$(this).find('.interestCheck').prop('checked'));
  var check = $(this).find('.interestCheck').val();
  $(this).find(".interestBox").toggleClass("active")
  console.log(check);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var interest = $('.interest');
interest.click(function() {
  $(this).find('.interestCheck').prop('checked', !$(this).find('.interestCheck').prop('checked'));
  var check = $(this).find('.interestCheck').val();
  $(this).find(".interestBox").toggleClass("active")
  console.log(check);
});
```

```css
.interest {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.interestBox.active {
  background: red;
}

.interestBox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.interestTitle {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.interestCheck {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Linear Motion</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Linear Motion" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Material Handling</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Material Handling" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Enclosures</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Enclosures" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the background color won't change to red now?

Comment: It's only solving the most obvious issue in OP's code. Not the other ones.

Comment: @Paul Check the updated demo, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I made you a very simple code of how you can click and get class active ( also checked true ) and then remove it when clicking on other images . So only one at the same time is active.

You need to make use of `this` keyword which means the element on which the event happens. You can then find the checkbox inside that element, change it's checked status and also find the `interestBox` you want to activate.

Also you find the other elements that may have been activated and deactivate them.

Your whole logic must be inside the click function. If you use the `if` outside the function, that condition will be executed on `window.load` or `dom.ready` etc, but it will executed BEFORE you click on the item. So the `if` is useless. It checks, sees that the checkbox is not checked and doesn't update and re-check the condition after the click event occurs.

```js
let interest = $('.interest');
interest.click(function() {
  let targetCheck = $(this).find('.interestCheck'),
    notCheck = $('.interestCheck').not(targetCheck)

  notCheck.prop('checked', false);
  notCheck.siblings(".interestBox").removeClass('active');


  targetCheck.prop('checked', true);
  targetCheck.siblings(".interestBox").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.interest {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.interestBox.active {
  background: red;
}

.interestBox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.interestTitle {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.interestCheck {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Linear Motion">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Linear Motion</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Linear Motion" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Material Handling">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Material Handling</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Material Handling" class="interestCheck">
</div>
<div class="interest">
  <div class="interestBox">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/linearIcon.png" alt="Enclosures">
  </div>
  <h3 class="interestTitle">Enclosures</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Enclosures" class="interestCheck">
</div>
```